# Как сделать push 2 веток сразу?

Tags: git

Подскажите как сделать git push 2 веток сразу?

Comment: Непонятен вопрос: одну ветку в несколько репозиториев или несколько веток одного репозитория? Если второе, то ответ уже дали.

Answer (score 1):

Так и делать

`git push`

Если нужно запушить две, а остальные не надо, то

`git push origin branch1 branch2`